# Is there a better way to write a code to find the palindromes of 3 digit numbers?

Tags: java

I have made a program to determine all the palindrome 3 digit numbers. Is there is much efficient way in which this program could be written?

```java
import java.lang.Math;

class New {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int prod = 0;int proda=0;
        int show = 0;
        for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int j = 100; j <= i; j++) {
                prod = i * j;
                show = prod;
                proda=prod;

                int sum=0;
                while(prod>0) {
                    prod=prod/10;
                    sum++;
                }

                int saum = 0;
                int p = 0;
                while (proda >0) {
                    p = (int) ((proda % 10) * (Math.pow(10,sum-1)));
                    saum += p;
                    proda = proda / 10;
                    sum--;
                }
                if (saum == show) {
                    System.out.println(show);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We prefer questions that can be answered without resorting to opinion. We also prefer questions that show some research or prior-effort on behalf of the poster. This question doesn't meet either of these criteria. Perhaps if you try to find a more efficient solution yourself and then ask for guidance on that particular solution?

Answer (score -1):

Three digit palindromes are $a b a$, with $1 \le a \le 9$ and $0 \le b \le 9$. Use that to generate them as fast as possible. This is just $101 \cdot a + 10 \cdot b$.

Comment: I have no idea what any of this means. Can you please explain it?